# why doesnt defining console.log in firefox source code work?

Tags: javascript, firefox, backwards-compatibility, console.log

a lot of websites do console.log-ing without any check for a console, so it breaks javascript on older browsers where console was not defined by the browser.
to prevent this, i wanted to define the console in the source code of my firefox 3.6.10. i tried adding this in the Mozilla Firefox\chrome\browser.jar\content\browser\browser.js source file (by extracting file, editing, adding it back):

```
if (typeof console == "undefined") {
window.console = {
    log: function () {}
};
alert('stuff');}
```

i tried adding it after the 'let gDownloadMgr = null;' line, inside the 'function pageShowEventHandlers(event)' function, and inside 'checkIdentity : function(state, location)' function.
it didnt work at any of these. 
the alert always showed, in the checkIdentity function when a https page was loaded and in the pageShowEventHandlers any time at least once when any page was loaded.
but writing the

```
javascript:console.log('stuff');void 0
```

in the address bar always returned the 'Error: console is not defined' in the error console...

putting the exact same code in the address bar like this:

```
javascript:if (typeof console == "undefined") {window.console = {log:function () {}};alert('stuff');};void 0
```

always resulted in having no error at all when doing a console.log after.

i even tried putting the whole thing in setInterval() with 3 second time so it surely gets executed when it should be.
nothing worked, i even tried setting it with 'var console' and even 'const console', with the if condition and without it. i also didnt find any addon or any other solution for this

Comment: Adding it to the browser code is the wrong approach. Firefox already *has* a console. That sort of thing is intended for code supplied by pages that the browser is viewing.

Comment: @Pointy — Firefox 3.6 doesn't … although why anybody would keep it installed now it is unsupported and doesn't get security fixes, I have no idea. Heck, 3.6.10 isn't even the most recent in the 3.6 branch, there are dozens of security issues fixed in the 16 point releases that followed it.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for trying to support Firefox 3.6?

Comment: sorry I didn't realize this was an archaeological issue :)

Comment: yes i have a good reason, a lot in fact. and none of these comments are any helpful. it was a javascript question not an "archaeological issue", that was very funny by the way. looks like people still believe what is newer is inherently better, and cant see past that. sorry for wasting MY time asking.